# How to have my code run until I enter a number

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

I'm sorry if this is a silly question but I am fairly new to coding and so for my assignment I was given this code:

```
package webservice;
import webservice.Weather;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
      System.out.print ("Enter the zip code : ");
      java.lang.String zipCode = scan.nextLine();
      try{  
           webservice.Weather service = new webservice.Weather();
           webservice.WeatherSoap port = service.getWeatherSoap();
           webservice.WeatherReturn result = port.getCityWeatherByZIP(zipCode);
           System.out.print(result.getCity()+ " ");
           System.out.println (result.getState());
           System.out.println("Zip code " + zipCode);
           System.out.println ("Current Temperature is " + result.getTemperature());
        }
      catch (Exception ex){
        System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }//end main
}//end class
```

The code runs perfectly fine but I have to have it loop until i enter "0" for the zip code.
I'm fairly new to coding and I tried to review my previous works to try to incorporate a loop but I was never successful. Which loop would be the most efficient to have the code loop until the user enters "0" as the zip code?

Answer (score 1):

How about while loop?

```
String zipCode;
while(!"0".equals(zipCode = scan.nextLine())) {
   //to do rest
}
```

Sample code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String zipCode;
        while(!"0".equals(zipCode = sc.nextLine())) {
            System.out.printf("zip code: %s\n", zipCode);
        }
        System.out.printf("last zip code: %s\n", zipCode);
    }
}
```

I/P:

```
123
456
789
0
```

O/P:

```
zip code: 123
zip code: 456
zip code: 789
last zip code: 0
```

Comment: I tried to run the corrections but adding that just allows me to enter as many zip codes but when i end it shows:
"0" it just says "Zip code 0" 
"Current Temperature is "

Comment: @StevenBelmonte, kindly find the sample code [working here](http://ideone.com/xenX05)

Answer (score 1):

Simply try this:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
int zipCode;
while(scan.nextInt()!=0){
 System.out.print ("Enter the zip code : ");
 zipCode = scan.nextInt();
}
```

Use a `while` loop to *verify your condition* and use `.nextInt()` to *get an int from the scanner*.

**Also there's a typo:**

If you use :

```
import webservice.Weather;
```

You don't have to do this:

```
webservice.Weather service = new webservice.Weather();
```

It's simply:

```
Weather service = new Weather();
```

Take a look at **[Using Package Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html)** for further information.

Answer (score 0):

while loop would do your trick.

This is because while loop checks the condition first and then iterates over if the condition is found to be true. And in your case we need to check if the user has entered the correct value or not. If he has entered 0 we do not need to proceed further.